# "There are two "that" in one sentence, what's the second "that" refers to?

Tags: optional-that

I see this sentence in my book:

> User interface configuration files like the one you just saved in the preceding section can be imported into Word 2010 and later on any other PC. Importing wipes out any customization settings on that PC, so make sure there are no customizations **that you can’t reproduce that you want to keep before doing this**.

I know the first **that** refers to customizations, but what's the second **that** refers to?

Comment: The second **that** also refers to customizations. It might be easier to understand if you add "and" before the second "that". Does that help?

Comment: The first "that" refers back to ***customisations***, but the *second* "that" refers to *customisations **that you can't reproduce*** (which are a specific *subset* of the aforementioned customisations).

Comment: What book? Please tell us.

Comment: @Lambie Microsoft Visio 2016 Step By Step (Michael LaRiviere's Library)

Comment: @FumbleFingers May you confirm your idea for your idea differentiates that of gotube in comments?

Comment: I see now that @gotube's first comment contains a "mistake", in that *if you add "and" before the first "that"* you'll end up with syntactically invalid text. But I never actually noticed that until just now, and obviously at least two other users (who upvoted that comment) didn't notice either. That's because gotube's *first* sentence is perfectly correct - and I was just adding further detail by pointing out that the second "that" refers to ***a specific subset*** of the customisations referenced by the first "that".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Fixed. Tx!

Comment: @FumbleFingers May you tell me why should we add **and** before the first **that** to test?

Comment: Syntactically (and maybe even idiomatically), the first "that" isn't *required*. It's fine to say *Just make sure there are no customisations you can't reproduce* (it's okay to have customisations, ***provided that you can reproduce them***). Your example sentence just takes that concept of "...with certain exceptions" a bit further, by saying that it's okay to have customisations even if you *can't* reproduce them, ***provided that you don't want to keep them***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers After having read your reply, I have understanded this sentence more deeply. However, I still don't know why you said to add an **and** before the first **that** when you replied to **gotube**.

Comment: I never *did* "reply to gotube"! But what I said in my *second* comment is that when I looked more closely at gotube's initial comment *the next day*, I realised that the second sentence of gotube's first comment is incorrect. Specifically, adding the word "and" as suggested would give us the syntactically invalid utterance *Make sure there are no customizations **and** that you can’t reproduce that you want to keep before doing this.* That text could in principle be made valid by changing it to *...reproduce **what** you want to keep...*, but that's a completely different structure / meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What did **gotube** say it to add **and** before the second **that**, so the sentence should be: *make sure there are no customizations that you can’t reproduce **and** that you want to keep before doing this*. But your answer to **gotobe** is to add **that** before the first **that**. Given that, I am curious why you did this before.

Comment: You don't seem to have noticed that gotube's initial comment has been ***changed*** since I pointed out the error! Originally he suggested adding the word ***and*** before the ***first*** instance of the word "that", which is *not valid*. Note that strictly speaking ***both*** instances of the word "that" in your highlighted text are syntactically "optional" - but although many native speakers would happily discard the *first* one, I think in practice no-one would discard the second one in this *exact* context (but they might well do so in some fairly similar constructions).

Answer (score 2):

Using parentheses to show the order of evaluation - much like in mathematics - we can notate the sentence as...

> there are no ((customizations that you can’t reproduce) that you want to keep)

In this case, because both "you can't reproduce" and "you want to keep" act to narrow the set of customisations under discussion, it ultimately means there are no customisations that: 1) you can't reproduce, and 2) you do want to keep.

Comment: So two **that** are parallelstructure?

Comment: You idea differentiates that of BillJ who answered this question too.

Comment: @Tony Delroy It would better to analyse it as a 'stacked' relative construction. See my answer for details.

Comment: @BillJ: I appreciate your answer and upvoted it yesterday, but don't think it's very accessible or useful to language learners that need to ask such a question, so I tried to provide an explanation that was accessible.  Given you also have your answer I'm not going to change mine - I think they complement each other as is.

Comment: @Y.zeng: I can't find any definition of parallel structure that includes examples with "that" ([this](https://www.evergreen.edu/sites/default/files/writingcenter/handouts/grammar/parallel.pdf) seems pretty comprehensive, but omits "that"), so maybe not, but I would personally agree it's similar structuring.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's no reason to post a misleading answer. If you think about it logically, the antecedent of the second "that" is not "customizations", but "customizations that you can't reproduce", hence the term 'stacking'. If a coordination is intended, the two clauses should be joined by "and", as in "customizations that you can’t reproduce and that you want to keep before doing this", though there would be a difference in meaning.

Comment: I agree with @BillJ's last comment. It just so happens that a slip-up in gotube's first comment under the question raises the possibility of introducing an "and" that doesn't work anyway (he was presumably assuming something like *...making sure there are no customizations **and** that you can’t reproduce **what / whatever / anything [that]** you want to keep before doing this*). But that seems to be confusing the OP here, so while I won't go so far as to *downvote* this answer, it's not obvious to me that it's actually helping the OP understand the construction he asked about.

Comment: @BillJ "though there would be a difference in meaning" - how would it differ in this particular sentence?  Anyway, my post doesn't actually answer "what's the second *that* refer to" - it just provides a simile ("works life a filter") to explain overall meaning.  You're actually answering the question - basically "(X that A) that B" - and I agree, correct and probably more appropriate, so I'll adjust my answer.  (It's interesting to consider say "I like objects that have curves that I can run my fingers around", where the correct way to understand it is as "X that (A that B)".)

Comment: @TonyDelroy The parallel structure I said is as this one: I like the car that my mother sent to me and that I have drived for ten years.

Comment: @Y.zeng in that case, you have and "and" that creates the parallel structure.

Answer (score 2):

> *... there are no customizations* [*that you can’t reproduce*] [*that you want to*
> *keep before doing this*].

Both "thats" introduce relative clauses, as bracketed.

This is an instance of the 'stacking' of relative clauses, where an integrated relative clause combines with its antecedent to form a larger unit which is antecedent for a second integrated relative clause.

Thus *that you can’t reproduce* combines with its antecedent *customizations* to give *customizations that you can’t reproduce* and this is then the antecedent for the second relative clause *that you want to keep before doing this*.